# Can I pigtail #6 to #12 or #10 to the breaker in a panel?

Tags: wiring

Running #6 120ft from dockhouse to end of dock on a 20a breaker.  #6 wire won't go into the breaker - can I pigtail a short piece of #12 or #10 in the panel?

Comment: Is that 6 AWG Copper or Aluminum?

Comment: For just 120 feet #6 seems like overkill for 20 amps.

Comment: The only ways 6 AWG makes sense is if (a) a 120V circuit, (b) limiting to 3% (not usually needed, but often done), and (c) either calculating based on 20A for copper or 16A for aluminum. Should be only calculating at 80% of capacity, so 16A. If this is aluminum and a true 80% continuous then 6 AWG *may* make sense -but then your splicing has to be something that can properly handle aluminum *or* splice to a smaller aluminum (not copper) wire.

Comment: Well I might recommend 6-6-6 or 6-6-6-6 aluminum as a cheaper option than #10 copper.  #6 copper is *bonkers* for 20A @ 120V. Possibly someone used a marine voltage drop chart intended for 24V, there's one of those floating around that frequently miseducates people.  Or they foresee a need for 40-50A dockside?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert from AWG 6 (for the long run to reduce voltage drop) to any size from AWG 12 (minimum for 20A copper) to the largest size your 20A breaker will take (Pretty sure mine go to AWG 8, and since it's a pigtail, it's not much wire cost.)

Panels are (very large) junction boxes.

Do make sure the connection is solid.

Answer (score 2):

NEC 312.8 has volume limits for cabinets containing overcurrent devices. Limits applying to a #6 to #12 splice are:

> (1) The total of all conductors installed at any any cross section
> of the wiring space does not exceed 40 percent of the cross  sectional area of that space.
>
> (2) The total area of all conductors, splices,
> and taps   at any cross section of the wiring space does not exceed 75
> percent  of the cross sectional area of that space.

So basically you can probably make that splice since it's hard to exceed those limits.